# how to cover constructor which have standardcontroller in test class

Tags: unit-test, standardcontroller

```
 public SFA_LeadNewOverride_VFC(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.mysObject = (sObject)stdController.getRecord();

        recId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get(LABEL.SFA_NEW_LEAD_ACC_FIELD_LKID);
        accName = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get(LABEL.SFA_NEW_LEAD_ACC_NAME_ID);

     }
```

I am trying this

```
 Lead leadRecord=new Lead();
                leadRecord.LeadSource='Web';
                leadRecord.Company='TestCompany';
                leadRecord.Status='Owner-Working';
                leadRecord.Rejection_Reason__c='not accepted';
                leadRecord.LastName='Ggg';
                leadRecord.Contact_Email__c='aaa@gmail.com';
                leadRecord.Country__c='India';
                leadRecord.Account_Name__c=acc.id;
                leadRecord.Contact__c=con.id;
                leadRecord.Email='asd@gmail.com';
                leadRecord.MobilePhone = '1234567890';
                leadRecord.Phone = '1234567890';
                insert leadRecord;

 ***SFA_LeadNewOverride_VFC objVFC = new SFA_LeadNewOverride_VFC(leadRecord);***
```

but it gives error in test class that is Compile Error:

> Constructor not defined: [SFA_LeadNewOverride_VFC].(Lead)
>   at line 55 column 51

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a standard controller with the lead record before passing it to your constructor. The constructor takes StandardController type variable and not an SObject. Try doing this:

```
ApexPages.StandardController leadStandardController = new ApexPages.StandardController(leadRecord);
SFA_LeadNewOverride_VFC objVFC = new SFA_LeadNewOverride_VFC(leadStandardController);
```

Comment: and what about to standardsetcontroller in constructor

Comment: public SFA_LeadNewOverride_VFC(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {

        
        recId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
       

        if(String.isNotBlank(recId) && recId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName() == 'Account'){
            accId = recId;
            accOnLead = [Select Id,Name FROM Account WHERE Id =:recId LIMIT 1];
        }

Answer (score 0):

The parameter for the method is a standard controller so you will need to do this:

```
SFA_LeadNewOverride_VFC objVFC = 
        new SFA_LeadNewOverride_VFC(
          New ApexPages.StandardController(
                leadRecord
           )
        );
```

Pass in a constructed standard controller